# Looking to find out what this old movie was I rented from Blockbuster as a kid

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, space

Not sure if it’s even possible to find out with this amount of detail but I rented a movie from Blockbuster as a kid but never got to watch the whole thing. It was a squad of soldiers going to a planet to retrieve something and they are attacked by aliens… pretty vague but they were almost dressed up as Spartans from Halo and one really stood out with like a red face/teeth drawn on his helmet.

Comment: "Blockbuster" dates this already a little, but you might still want to add when you were a kid.

Comment: What year did you rent the film? Was it VHS or DVD? Can you remember how they got to the planet? Were the aliens humanoid or distincly alien? Was the colour of the suits Spartan green or some other colour?

Comment: I want to say Starship Troopers 2, but I can't find any relevant images of the helmet.

Comment: following @mwarren, could have been the animated Starship Troopers Chronicles. Was it live action or animated?